# How to make elements is one below the other on mobile screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have calendar I try achieve that elements are one below other on mobile screens and on tablet screens.  Right now are arranged next to each other on mobile screens, i want to avoid the scroll.  Here is  what I want to achieve. 
[This is a plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAeoc.png)
Here is test web on this [link](https://testmihzg.herokuapp.com/index.html)

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Please include the code so that the problem can be diagnosed properly. Here is a guide to presenting a question effectively [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be enough to change the `flex-direction` of the event `ul`.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .cd-schedule .events .events-group > ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Of course then you can style with margin / padding to have some spaces between them and change the media query to reflect what you need.